# Why do we not use the <script> tag for calling the function 'alert 'in HTML?

Tags: html

For the popping an alert box on a button click,we use the alert method that is JavaScript, right?

I haven't seen any code that surrounds the call to alert inside the `onclick` attribute in a `'<script>'` tag.

Comment: which is actually the question?

Comment: You mean you're putting the code in <buttons> onclick attirbute?

Answer (score 1):

**Event Attributes**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Event_attributes

That's cause `onclick` inside a html tag **is** read by the browser as **JavaScript**

```
<a id='el' onclick=' /*Everything here is JS*/ alert("HEY"); '>CLICK ME TO ALERT</a>
```

Otherwise you'd **preferably** use `script` tags before your `</body>` tag:

```
<a id='el'>CLICK ME TO ALERT</a>

<script>
    var el = document.getElementById("el");
    el.onclick = function(){
       alert("HEY!");
    };
</script>
```

or using `addEventListener` method on the `"click"` Event :

```
<a id='el'>CLICK ME TO ALERT</a>

<script>
    var el = document.getElementById("el");
    el.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("HEY!");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do not need to add  tags within the button onclick function. This is because onclick is a JavaScript event handler built into the HTML. The onclick already knows that there will be JavaScript inside the event listener, so there is no need for the  tags.

Answer (score 0):

Roko and Eric has given a good answer.

Everything inside an onclick attibute is treated as a javascript function call by the browser.

If you use user define function then the browser expects that you define it in script tag. Otherwise, no script tag is needed.

Onclick = "---some javascript function call here --"

For e.g.

Onclick = "fun()" ----script tag is needed to define this function.

Onclick = "alert()" ---- script tag is not needed to define this function as it is predefined.

www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp